# esptool.py error Cannot configure port, something went wrong. PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)

Tags: serial, esp8266, arduino-ide

When trying to upload my firmware to an ESP8266 board using Arduino IDE 2.2.1 I get

```
A fatal esptool.py error occurred: Cannot configure port, something went wrong. Original message: PermissionError(13, 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.', None, 31)
```

All of my research says that this is a CH340 driver problem, this is not the case. I did try reinstalling the driver. I use Termite as a Serial Monitor which communicates with my ESP8266 just fine. I can use the Arduino Web Editor and upload to the serial port through the Arduino Create with no issue, this has to be an Arduino specific issue are there any fixes for this?

Comment: try another version of the Arduino IDE

Comment: Same here, exactly the same problem. I did uninstall and update the driver and it still throws this error.